# Why MS Edge adds style position: absolute in host component?

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge

I have recently discovered that MS edge  adds magically style **position** with **absolute**. Does anyone have idea why it happens and what can I do against it ? It has impect to my style, that's why need to remove this magic.

```
<my-home class="ng-star-inserted" style="position: absolute;" _nghost-my-app-c23="">
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code example via stackblitz? Also, which MS Edge version are you refering to?

Comment: The above description and the HTML code are not enough to find the cause of the said issue. As another community member said, please inform us of the MS Edge version, Angular version and try to provide the detailed steps with the sample code. It can really help us to understand and test the issue on our side and based on the test results we can try to provide you further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.